# Figcaption position within card - how to?

Tags: html, css

I use a masonry-look for my cards like that here https://codepen.io/daiaiai/pen/VPXGZx

There I want to add some infos via figcaptions on top of the image/figure. I tried to do that with position:relative but that doesn't work. I wanna avoid using a negative margin-top but I can't think of a different solution. What/How should one do that?

Same as on codepen, but the raw "code" for css:

```
body { 
  margin: 0; background: #131212;  
} 
div#masonry { 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vw;
  max-height: 800px;
  font-size: 0;  
}
div#masonry figure {  
  width: 33.3%;
  transition: .8s opacity;
} 

figcaption{
  position:relative;
  top:100px;
  left:50px;
}

figure img{
  max-width:100%;
}
```

and that html-code

```
<div id="masonry">
<figure><figcaption>This girl</figcaption><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/1.jpg"></figure>
<figure><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/2.jpg"></figure>
<figure><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/3.jpg">
</figure>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not seeing the `figcaption` is because you have set the `font-size` of `#masonry` to 0, perhaps to remove spaces between columns.

You need to assign a `font-size` to `figcaption` to correct this.

I would also recommend changing how you position it.

Add `position: relative` to `figure`, and `position: absolute` to `figcaption`.

[**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/MJVqmJ)

**SNIPPET:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #131212;
}
div#masonry {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vw;
  max-height: 800px;
  font-size: 0;
}
div#masonry figure {
  width: 33.3%;
  transition: .8s opacity;
  position: relative;
}
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: auto;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
figure img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
/* fallback for earlier versions of Firefox */

@supports not (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  div#masonry {
    display: block;
  }
  div#masonry img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="masonry">
  <figure>
    <figcaption>This girl</figcaption>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/1.jpg">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/2.jpg">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/3.jpg">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/4.jpg">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/6.jpg">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/8.jpg">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/9.jpg">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/7.jpg">
  </figure>
  <figure>
</div>
```